# Calling Rails helper from rabl Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

I'm trying to call a Rails helper from my `rabl` template, but it's not working.

I have an image object and I want to pass its pass through my api. So then image path should have the full url (Ex: `http://<my url>/uploads/myimage.jpg`). The host part I want to add through a Rails helper.

```
#my rabl file
object @image
attributes :id, :picture_url
```

What I want is something like (I tried this but doesn't work)

```
#my rabl file
object @image
attributes :id, full_url(:picture_url)

#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def full_url(path)
    "#{request.host}#{path}" #something like this
  end
end
```

But when I do this, it completely drop the `:picture_url` attribute from the `json` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this might work for you:

```
object @image
attributes :id
node(:picture_url) { full_url(:picture_url) }
```

`node` allows you to define things that do not directly map to object attributes.

**EDIT 1**

It looks like I got the `node` syntax wrong.  Try this instead:

```
node(:picture_url) { |i| full_url(i.picture_url) }
```

Comment: Quick question though, it seems like its not reading the value of the attribute, it takes the attribute as a string, Ex if the attribute value of the path say 'my_image.gif' , it gives me back `http://localhost:3000/path` instead of `http://localhost:3000/my_image.gif`.. any idea ?. Im on rails 4.1.5

Comment: @sameera207 looks like I got the syntax wrong for node.  I updated my answer to have the correct syntax.

Comment: Hey , thanks ... what I actually did was  `node(:picture_url) { full_url(@image) }`, I pass the object and got the url from the object. but your updated answer looks more cleaner.. I'll update my code thanks

Answer (score 0):

By calling `full_url(:picture_url)`, `attributes` gets a string that doesn't correspond to a method on the `@image` object, i.e., `@image.id` returns something, while `@image.http://...` isn't even valid :).

I would suggest you leave the view as it was first, and set the value of the `@image.picture_url` using your helper in the controller.