# Calling Rails helper inside a rabl collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

I want to call a Rails helper method from my `rabl` template. I was able to it [via Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049246/calling-rails-helper-from-rabl-rails) for one object.

This is my current setup (and it's working fine)

I have a helper

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper

  def full_url(image)
    "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{image.picture_url}" if recipe.image
  end

end


#app/images/show.rabl
object @image
attributes :id, :picture_url
node(:picture_url) { full_url(@image) }
```

Now I want to do this for a list of image objects, but its not working and I cannot find it in `rabl` README.

The problem is it passes the `@images` list , I'm not sure how to call an the helper method on each individual object

```
#app/images/index.rabl
collection @images
attributes :id, 
node(:picture_url) { full_url(@images) }
```

Comment: What's `full_url`? Should it be `thumb_url`?

Comment: @BroiSatse, sorry.. my bad, it is supposed to be `full_url` , I was simplifying my code and got a typo. I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a param to your node block:

```
collection @images
attributes :id, :picture_url
node(:picture_url) {|image| full_url(image) }
```